# How does recursion work?

Tags: java, recursion

Please explain how recursion works, in the simplest way you can.

Comment: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.  `</obligatory>`

Comment: what do you mean by first understand recursion

Comment: Yeah, @SLaks, where's your base case??

Comment: It's a joke, Lexy, playing off the self-referential nature of recursion (a recursive function references/calls itself). Don't worry about it - just review the answers below.

Comment: Look here for the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885105/how-does-recursion-work

Comment: You're going to confuse the poor guy, @rich. :)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta No royal way to it, recursion **is** confusing! :)

Comment: The story is incomplete if you don't provide a base case. Showing an infinite recursion pattern is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of recursive method: -

```
public int recur(int count) {
   if (count < 10) {
       return count + recur(count++);
   }
   return count;
}

System.out.println(recur(0));  // Invoke first time
```

Comment: yes i understand when in working with numbers but for example i am making this method that erase an element from an arraylist if the element start with an specific char. here is the method:

Comment: @LexyFeito Then you should have asked that specific question with some code you tried..

Comment: private static ArrayList deleteItems(ArrayList<String> table, char ch)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2.add("hey");
        if(table.isEmpty() || table.size() == 0) {
            return list2;
        }
        
        if(table.get(0).charAt(0) == ch){
            
            table.remove(0);
            return deleteItems(table, ch);
        }else{
            list2.add(table.get(0));
            table.remove(0);
            return deleteItems(table, ch);
        }
        
        
    }

Comment: Post that in your question body, not down here in a comment, @Lexy. And be sure to specify what your actual **question** about that code is.

Comment: im still learning how to work in this site i tried to do what you are saying but it doesn't let me it gives me an error

Comment: I mean this in the best possible way, @Lexy: to become a programmer, you must learn to provide a better problem description than "it gives me an error".

Comment: You right sorry but i found out the problem thank you for help

Answer (score 7):

As been pointed out, recursion is when a function calls itself. Here illustrated using `factorial`, where `factorial(5)` mathematically evalutates to values `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1`.

```
public int factorial(int x) {
   if (x == 1) return 1;
   else return x * factorial (x - 1);
}

// Try routine
factorial(3);
```

Which evaluates as

```
 factorial(1) = 1                                        = 1
 factorial(2) = 2 * factoral(1)                          = 2 * 1 
 factorial(3) = 3 * (2 * factorial(2) * (factorial(1))   = 3 * 2 * 1
 ...
```

Comment: The value of 0! is 1, so this line `if (x == 1) return 1;` should be `if (x == 0) return 1;`

Answer (score 4):

Usually, it's a function that *calculates one result itself, and calls itself to get the rest of the results*.

For example, to get all positive numbers less or equal to 3, the function says, "One result is 3, and the rest of the results are all positive numbers less or equal to 2. Let's call myself with 2 and add that result to the one I calculated."

Of course, recursive functions need to be careful to have an "end condition" or they will never return a result. In the case of this example, the end condition would be when the function is called with 0, it should just return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a method which calls itself from within itself.

Example:

```
public void recur(int x)
    recur(10);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is when a function calls itself:

```
int factorial(int integer)
{
    if (integer == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (integer*(factorial(integer-1)));
}
```