# Could someone explain to me how this function works? (recursion)

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void main(string[]args) {
    system.out.println(sum5(10));
}
public static void sum5(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    return sum5(n - 1) + n;
}
```

The results of this function is 55.
How's does this method work?

Comment: Do you understand recursion?

Comment: I don't know what your code does, since the main method calls the method `sum()`, but you've only provided us with the code for the method `sum5()`.

Comment: i understand but i don't know why the result are 55

Comment: 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 55

Comment: If you step through your code in your debugger you can se what each line of code does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does recursion work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885105/how-does-recursion-work)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this is a summation from 1 to n

`sum5(3)` basically calculates (3 + 2 + 1)

Just think how it would look like in the computer, I will do it with `sum5(3)`

```
call sum5(3)
 1. n != 0 thus return sum5(2) + 3
 2. n != 0 thus return sum5(1) + 2
 3. n != 0 thus return sum5(0) + 1
 4. n == 0 thus return 0
 now we go back up
 sum5(1) = sum5(0) + 1 => 1 | sum5(0) = 0 from last step.
 sum5(2) = sum5(1) + 2 => 3 | sum5(1) = 1 from last step.
 sum5(3) = sum5(2) + 3 => 6 | sum5(2) = 3 from last step.
```

P.S In order to understand recursion you must first understand recursion
*Pun intended.*

Answer (score 1):

In natural language the function returns its parameter plus the value of the call to itself with the parameter decrease by 1 - kind of its predecessor.

Which gives you 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 55

This is very basic stuff, you should read up on recursion in some introductory computer science book.