# Java - Recursion to find the 2 smallest nums in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

So I have this problem of finding the 2 smallest numbers in array but I have to use recursion (the recursion part is a part of this exercise).
I start thinking how to do it and 'the plan' that I trying to do is like this, first of all find the smallest in the array, then mark where I found it and then to split the array in to 2 groups and search in this 2 group an eventuality take the minimum from them..

this is the code that I got this far:

```
public static int MinRecu2(int[] a) {
    if (a.length == 1)
        return a[0];
    int min = a[0];
    int min2;
    int mark = 0;

    // Find first min
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < min) {
            min = a[i];
            mark = i;
        }
    }

    int [] help1= new int [mark+1];
    int [] help2= new int [a.length-mark];
    help1=Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mark);
    help2=Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mark+1, a.length-1);

    // Find second min
    min2 = Math.min(MinRecu2(help1), MinRecu2(help2));

    return min;
}
```

I know the code not working and that the 'recursion' I was trying to do is bad, but that how I was trying to make my thinking to code

Comment: where did you try to implement recursion?

Comment: [For an example of recursion with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885105/how-does-recursion-work)

Comment: Try sort the array using java.util.Arrays.sort(int[])

Comment: @rjdkolb: this is an academic assignment, and I'm guessing that what you suggest isn't allowed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my bad.. I didn't change the function name, look now

Comment: @Stultuske look my comment above :)

Comment: The problem with your approach is that the recursive calls will again try to find a second minimum (third overall) and so on. This makes it much more expensive as it needs to be.

Comment: Your code will go on forever as you're passing in the same array into your recursive calls, so the array's length never gets smaller, meaning that your recursive stopping condition, that the array's length == 1, is never reached.

Comment: @Henry so I was thinking the wrong way.. mmm any suggesting for a new way of thinking about this problem?

Comment: First off, get rid of the for loop and simplify.  Work through examples of recursion with arrays first. Be sure that the array passed into the recursive call is *smaller* than the current size.... you'll figure this out, but keep at it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did try using Arrays.copyOfRange() with the mark, didn't work either

Comment: "didn't work" tells us little of use...

Comment: Or you can use the same array, but pass in an index value that changes with each recursion....

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so I change it and split it but I still get out of bound int the array

Comment: You’re not that far from your goal. Write a recursive method to find the single minimum of an array. Call it instead of the loop under `// Find first min` and again on the two subarrays `help1` and `help2`. Now you have found both `min` and `min2`, and you have used recursion for it. I think it would make for a nice solution.

Comment: Down-vote retracted. Thank you for posting your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach to your question.

```
public static int[] twoSmallest(int[] arr, int s, int e) {
    int[] list;
    if (e - s <= 3) { // maybe 2 or 3
        list = new int[e - s];
        for (int i = s; i < e; i++)
            list[i - s] = arr[i];
    } else {
        int[] left = twoSmallest(arr, s, (s + e) / 2);
        int[] right = twoSmallest(arr, (s + e) / 2, e);
        list = new int[4];
        list[0] = left[0];
        list[1] = left[1];
        list[2] = right[0];
        list[3] = right[1];
    }
    Arrays.sort(list);
    return new int[] {list[0], list[1]};
}
```

This function means find two smallest numbers in `arr` in [s, e). You can call like this:

```
int[] result = twoSmallest(arr, 0, arr.length);
```

Comment: thanks, I will look at it now and try to see where did I did wrong

Answer (score -1):

```
private static int findMinFromArray(int[] iArray, int index, int min) {
    if(index <= (iArray.length - 1)){
        if(iArray[index] < min){
            min = iArray[index];
        }
        System.out.println("Before: " + "Index = " + index + " | Min = " + min);
        findMinFromArray(iArray, index + 1, min);
    }
    System.out.println("After: " + "Index = " + index + " | Min = " + min);
    return min;
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the program to stop, rather than going back again like it's doing.This finds only smallest.