# Explanation for printing 1 to 10 in Java

Tags: java, recursion

Firstly there are many example code available everywhere for this question. However my question is about how it is achieving it, not just the result. So please don't term it as DUPLICATE.

The code below successfully prints the numbers 1 to 10 (Note: not 10 to 1). I tried debugging to understand how it does but it was not clear.

I have the breakpoints in lines 1,2,3 and 4. After line-4 the code goes to line-1 and line-2 recursively till the value of n reduces from 10 to 0. After the value of n becomes 0, the line-3 is executed for printing all numbers from 1 to 10. I can't understand how this works. Can someone explain.

```
public class print1to10 {

    static void printNos(int n)
    {
1.      if(n > 0)
        {
2.          printNos(n - 1);
3.          System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
4.      printNos(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a simple recursive call. how do you think it works?

Comment: After the value of n reaches 0, how ONLY the line 3 is called to print all values from 1 to 10 is where i can't understand

Comment: search how Stack memory works, start from https://www.baeldung.com/java-recursion

Comment: Before downvoting please give the answer. Please dont say recursive call. It is clear is recursive call.

Comment: Try drawing out how the specific lines are fired(e.g. a chart or whatnot). This might help you see why this is happening.

Comment: I suggest reading about what recursion is and how it works. You will also need to understand what the call stack is.

Comment: @truespan What part don't you understand? Is it the order (1 to 10 rather than 10 to 1)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will look them up. To get these suggestions i have to get so many downvotes. Thank you.

Comment: @truespan I see where you're coming from, but complaining about downvotes won't do much, so you may as well not do it.

Comment: I guess, i was missing how the stack works in this case. Thank you all for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple recursive call, like @Stultuske said.

You call the function printNos with the argument 10 and before you are able to print it, you call printNos with 9. The jump-point is saved to the stack. This way you reach the "bottom of calls" with an argument of 0 which stops the recursive calls - the 10th instance of printNos is closed. After that the stack is worked up and you start in the 9th instance with the print-statement. The argument was 1. It is printed and this instance is closed. The next one is 2, then 3 and so on. After the last open instance the program is terminated and you have the expected result printed. No magic :-)

Get more infos here:

https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

[How does recursion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885105/how-does-recursion-work)