# Calling method name inside same method?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, binary-tree, nodes

I'm confused on the application of calling method names inside that method.  I'll show with an example.

```
void executeIt(Node current) {
```

This is a pretend method called "executeIt" that takes a node called current. Underneath the method, something like the following code could exist:

```
    if (current == null) 
        return;
    if (current.getNext() != null) {
         System.out.println(current.getNext().getData() + " "); }
    executeIt(current.getNext());
```

This is just an example snippet of code.  The getNext() portion refers to the node following the current node (the one we are on), while the getData() method just refers to getting the data attached to the node (for example, if each node was carrying information about a person's name).

I'm confused as to what the second "executeIt()" method call is actually doing and why you would use it-- or what replaces it.  Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: It's just a plain normal method call with an argument that is whatever `current.getNext()` returns. Very simple and clear. Please be more precise with what you don't understand.

Comment: It's called recursion. To understand it, I'd suggest you take some pen and paper, and try to draw out what's happening after each line is executed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885105/how-does-recursion-work

Comment: I guess I just don't know why the method name is being called inside the method.  Because the point of executeIt is to return something (in the case, at least) but why would we call the method name inside of the same method?  That's the part that I'm stuck on.

Comment: This is called [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648062/calling-method-name-inside-same-method#comment109047548_61648062).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does recursion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885105/how-does-recursion-work)